# Java beats C++ on recursive algorithm speed comparison on my simple test

Tags: java, c++, performance

With this divide and conquer algorithm (Programming Pearls p80) to find the max sum found in any contiguous subvector of an array, the Java program is faster than the C++ counterpart tested on Win7 x64 with 8GB of RAM.

Both of Java and C++ runs on 1 CPU core.

What kind of optimization is done on the JVM to make this possible?

JVM 1 used:

Java version "1.6.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_21-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0-b17, mixed mode) 
VM Argument -Xmx12000m

JVM 2 used:
jrockit-jdk1.6.0_24-R28.1.3-4.0.1 
VM argument -Xmx12000m

C++ compiler:

Default Microsoft compiler that comes with Visual Studio 2008 x64

Times:

```
 //Java JVM 1, Oracle JRE
 //0x1fffffff: about 38s, sum 144115187270549505
 //0x2fffffff: about 56s, sum 324259171962716161
 //0x3fffffff: about 81s, sum 576460750692810753

 //Java JVM 2, Oracle JRockit jrockit-jdk1.6.0_24-R28.1.3-4.0.1
 //0x1fffffff: about 46s
 //0x2fffffff: about 69s
 //0x3fffffff: about 95s     

 //Cpp
 //0x1fffffff: around 45s, x64 Release
 //0x2fffffff: around 68s, x64 Release sum: 324259171962716161
 //0x3fffffff: around 93s, x64 Release sum: 576460750692810753,
```

```java
final int MAX = 0x3fffffff; 
Pearls1 pearls1 = new Pearls1();
pearls1.arr = new int[MAX];
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    pearls1.arr[(int) i] = i;                
}
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
long sum = pearls1.binaryForce(0, MAX - 1);
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long binaryForce(long lower, long upper) {
    //std::cout << "binaryForce("<< lower << ","<< upper <<")" << std::endl;

    if( lower > upper ) {
        return 0;
    } 
    if( lower == upper ) {      
        return Math.max( 0L, arr[(int) lower] ) ;       
    }

    long middle = ( lower + upper ) /2 ;

    long lmax = 0,  sum = 0;

    for( long i = middle; i >=lower; i-- ) {
        sum += arr[(int) i];        
        lmax = Math.max( lmax, sum);
    }

    long rmax = 0;
    sum = 0;

    //for( long i = middle+1; i <= upper; i++ ) {
    for( long i = upper; i > middle; i-- ) {
        sum += arr[(int) i];
        rmax = Math.max(rmax, sum);     
    }

    long theMax = lmax+rmax;

    long binarySumLeft = binaryForce(lower, middle);
    long binarySumRight = binaryForce(middle+1, upper);

    if( theMax > binarySumLeft && theMax > binarySumRight ) {
        return theMax;
    }
    else if( binarySumLeft > theMax && binarySumLeft > binarySumRight ) {
        return binarySumLeft;
    }
    else if ( binarySumRight > theMax && binarySumRight > binarySumLeft ) {
        return binarySumRight;
    }

    else {
        return theMax;      
    }

}
```

```c
 int main(...) {
    MAX = 0x3fffffff;
    arr = new long[MAX];
    for( long i=0;i<MAX;i++) {
        //arr[i] = rand();
        arr[i] = i;
    }

    timeb startTime, endTime;
    ftime( &startTime);
    std::cout << "Start time: " << startTime.time << " sec, " << startTime.millitm << " ms" << std::endl;

    sum = binaryForce(0, MAX-1);
    std::cout << "sum: " << sum <<std::endl;
    ftime( &endTime);
    std::cout << "End time: " << endTime.time << " sec, " << endTime.millitm << " ms" << std::endl;

    long runTimeSec = endTime.time - startTime.time;
    long runTimeMs = endTime.millitm - startTime.millitm;

    std::cout << "Run time: " << runTimeSec << " sec, " << runTimeMs << " ms" << std::endl;
 }

long long binaryForce(long lower, long upper) {
    //std::cout << "binaryForce("<< lower << ","<< upper <<")" << std::endl;

    if( lower > upper ) {
        return 0;
    } 
    if( lower == upper ) {        
        return std::max( 0L, arr[lower] ) ;        
    }

    long middle = ( lower + upper ) /2 ;

    long long lmax = 0,  sum = 0;

    for( long i = middle; i >=lower; i-- ) {
        sum += arr[i];        
        lmax = std::max( lmax, sum);
    }

    long long rmax = 0;
    sum = 0;

    //for( long i = middle+1; i <= upper; i++ ) {
    for( long i = upper; i > middle; i-- ) {
        sum += arr[i];
        rmax = std::max(rmax, sum);        
    }

    long long theMax = lmax+rmax;

    long long binarySumLeft = binaryForce(lower, middle);
    long long binarySumRight = binaryForce(middle+1, upper);

    if( theMax > binarySumLeft && theMax > binarySumRight ) {
        //std::cout << arr[theMax] << std::endl;
        return theMax;
    }
    else if( binarySumLeft > theMax && binarySumLeft > binarySumRight ) {
        //std::cout << arr[binarySumLeft] << std::endl;
        return binarySumLeft;
    }
    else if ( binarySumRight > theMax && binarySumRight > binarySumLeft ) {
        //std::cout << arr[binarySumRight] << std::endl;
        return binarySumRight;
    }

    else {
        //std::cout << arr[theMax] << std::endl;
        return theMax;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Where's the C++ code?

Comment: It also depends on your c++ code... you should provide it as well.

Comment: Are both processes running at the same bit-depth? (32 or 64)

Comment: Are you turning on optimisations for the C++ compiler (e.g. -O3 with gcc)

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner He does this, look at the comment in the code section

Comment: @portoalet: I'm voting to close. You're not providing the benchmarks used or the real performance numbers (aside from all of 6 aggregate numbers), the C++ code used, or the compiler/runtime used for each language.

Comment: No corresponding C++ code = not a real question.

Comment: My Blue car beats Red cars on straight-line speed, unless it's been optimised with a racing stripe.

Comment: You're using `long long` in the C++ version, and `long` in the java version. 128-bit arithmetic is definitely going to be slower.

Comment: hm, long long in visual studio is 64bits right? When I use just long, it truncates into 4billion mark.

Comment: @phooji @James McNellis : added the cpp code and jvm used and compiler types, reopen?

Comment: @portoalet: Oops, I think you're right.

Comment: It is worth nothing that Java is particulary good at detecting code which doesn't do anything and eliminating it. (Possibly better than C++ which has static means such as macros to "turn off" code.) This feature may not be as useful in real programs.  I would try the latest Java 6 release as it has a number of JVM improvements.

Comment: What flags are you passing to cl when compiling the C++ program?  `/O2`?  `/DEBUG`?

Comment: it's release, so /NDEBUG, and yes /O2 to maximize speed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java uses a Just-in-Time compiler at runtime to compile the bytecode into the appropriate machine code for the architecture you're running on. As it runs, it collects execution metrics to examine what the code is doing; if it determines a more optimal mechanism that doesn't alter the results of the code, it will recompile the code that runs, which means it's optimized for the most-commonly-used paths.

C++ doesn't do this, as it's optimized using a series of static optimizations. Java can do those, but the JIT means that the optimizations can be aimed at the data you're using, too.

You're not saying which JVM you're using, either. Different JVMs have different characteristics. JRockit, for example, will actually optimize much better than the standard Oracle JVM will, although it also takes much longer to warm up.

Comment: In principle, it’s an interesting question to analyse what exactly the JVM does to make the above code perform faster than when statically analysed; especially since the speed-up is rather large. The points you raise in your last paragraph are valid though.

Comment: Sure, it's definitely an interesting question - but consider a simple code path: "if(a()) {b();} else {c();}". What if a() changes very rarely, but usually returns false, and the else block takes longer than the block after the if()? Static optimization can't determine which value a() will yield most often; it has to use the code as expressed. The JVM can invert the code as it likes, to give execution priority to c()'s invocation. And if, at some point, a() returns true *most* of the time? The JVM can *recompile* the block again.

Comment: @Joseph I’m aware of this, and yes, that can happen. My point is: it would really be interesting to investigate a real-world case of such an example (such as in the OP’s problem) and see how such an optimisation *really* works. For one thing, the collecting of execution metrics must have a significant overhead. When does the JVM stop? Similarly, how would this perform against a profile-guided optimisation of an equivalent C++ code? Interesting questions worth investigating (but with a better defined problem). That said, your answer got my +1.

Comment: Thanks - and the JVM doesn't stop. For some JVMs you can pass in JVm arguments to see what optimizations it does (at the cost of runtime speed, as it's diagnostic information) - it's really instructive to see when and what kind of optimizations it makes. And in the real world, it's obviously a crucial feature - although it also invalidates all the stupid "C++ is faster than Java" and "Java is faster than C++" arguments, IMO, as it's really dependent on the actual problems being worked on.

Comment: @Joseph See, as somebody who doesn’t know anything about JIT optimization, you’ve got me hooked: how can the JVM continue to instrument the code without incurring an overhead which will negate any performance gains? I’ll have to investigate this …

Comment: @portoalet: be prepared to wait - JRockit's warmup can be an hour long. Once the warmup passes, depending on the nature of the code being measured, the improvements can be drastic and rather surprising.

@Konrad: there IS an overhead, of course. But the overhead is very slight, and the gains are worth it. The people who design these JVMs are just plain scary, in terms of how freaking bright they are.

Comment: Tested quickly with out of the box jrockit-jdk1.6.0_24-R28.1.3-4.0.1, it was slower than regular JRE1.6 by about 15%

Comment: @Joseph Ottinger , i am running it as a console app, not a server app, so i don't get it when you say "JRockit's warmup can be an hour long"

Comment: @portoalet: not surprising at all. There's no difference between a "console app" and a "server app" - they're both just applications that run in the JVM. It's not at all surprising that JRockit was slower in a test that ran in under two minutes. If the test runs for *over an hour*, well, then I'd start to wonder what was going on if you didn't see JRockit speed up quite a bit.

Comment: @Joseph Ottinger: Your if-statement example requires some further nuance. Yes, in principle, a JVM could recompile based on branch frequency. For a single if-statement with a strong bias towards one of the branches, however, the hardware branch predictor would be much more effective than a path-based recompilation of the code, since it is essentially overhead-less.

Comment: @phooji: Agreed. My example was meant to illustrate the concept, not the actuality, since on SO we're limited to ~500 characters in comments - nuance is difficult to convey. It wasn't meant to be a deterministic statement.

Comment: Just a bit strange why JRockit runs 15% slower than regular JRE in my test. It must have been optimized some other way like @Joseph Ottinger said

Comment: No, on startup JRockit is barely optimizing at all. So it makes sense you're getting poor performance from code that isn't being made to run well.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here but an int in C++ is represented as 32 bits (4 bytes) -- on a 64 bit system the kernel needs to perform 2 operations to access an int: 1/ read a WORD (64 bit) then 2/ apply an AND mask to reduce this to 32 bit. JVM as far as I know would probably store internally the int as a 64 bit but it's only at the point when you are reading this you will get the AND bitwise operator applied (i.e. sums/comparisons/etc will be done on 64 bit valued under the cover).
Try to change the C++ code to use a WORD data structure (64 bit) or run the same on 32-bit processor.

Comment: There’s no need to apply the AND mask.

Comment: Likewise: Why do you think the operation is needed? Can you think of any example where that’s the case? A mask does not “reduce … to 32 bit”. Depending on where the integer is located (register, cache), there may indeed be a reduction necessary (or not!) but that is done simply by copying four instead of eight bytes.

Comment: sorry, i see where the confusion occurs -- it won't reduce it to 32 bits however it will wipe out the first 32 bits (in case of overflow). That's what I meant -- hopefully it makes sense now?

Comment: Wiping out these bits is usually not required. The overflow which may occur can (and will) simply be ignored. There are operators which cannot ignore the overflow, but such operator do not exist in C++.